# Python nested for loop runs only once

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having problem with nested for loop (for doc in query) that is ran only once. It's inside for item in news_items which I have verified iterates 10 times, and the for doc in query loop should iterate 9 times. When I'm printing doc, it prints 9 documents, however as I'm trying to make if / else check on the document's content, it only happens to run one time. (I would expect 9 x 10 outputs since it's checking item from parent, to doc in query but all I get is 9 outputs).
I've tried to look on stack but nothing I found seems to be relevant, from other programing languages I work with I don't see why this wouldn't work but maybe I'm missing something since I'm fairly new to Python (1 week).

```
def scrape(url):
# GET DATE AT THE TIME OF CRAWL START
today = date.today()
d1 = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
# D2 is used for query only
d2 = today.strftime("%Y%m%d")
# LOAD URL IN DRIVER
driver.get(url)
try:
    news_container = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "FlashNews-Box-Root"))
    )
    # array of items
    news_items = news_container.find_elements_by_class_name("FlashNews-Box-Item")

    refresher_ref = db.collection(u'news').document('sources').collection('refresher_news')

    # query for last article
    query = refresher_ref.order_by(u'article_timestamp', direction=firestore.Query.DESCENDING).limit(10).stream()

    for item in news_items:
        print("News items found: " + str(len(news_items)))
        try:
            # image is optional so we need to try it
            try:
                item_image = item.find_element_by_class_name("FlashNews-Box-ItemImage").find_element_by_tag_name(
                    "img").get_attribute("src")
            except Exception as e:
                item_image = "unavailable"

            # time will be added to the same day as when this was ran, since this will run often and compare
            # article texts, we won't have issue with wrong dates
            item_time = item.find_element_by_class_name("FlashNews-Box-ItemTime").text + " " + d1
            item_time_query_temp = item.find_element_by_class_name("FlashNews-Box-ItemTime").text.replace(":", "")
            # normalize timestamp for sorting
            if len(item_time_query_temp) == 3:
                item_time_query_temp = "0" + item_time_query_temp

            item_time_query = d2 + item_time_query_temp
            item_text = item.find_element_by_class_name("FlashNews-Box-ItemText").text
            item_redirect = item.find_element_by_class_name("FlashNews-Box-ItemText").find_element_by_tag_name(
                "a").get_attribute("href")
            result = {"article_time": item_time, "article_url": item_redirect, "article_image": item_image,
                      "article_text": item_text, "article_timestamp": item_time_query}
            # print(result)
            # save data to firestore - check for last item in firestore, then add this article
            is_new = True

            print("Printing 10x")
            # THIS EXECUTES ONLY ONCE?
            for doc in query:
                # print(str(len(query)))
                current_doc = doc.to_dict()
                # print(current_doc)
                # print(current_doc)
                # print("Iteration: " + current_doc['article_text'])
                # print("Old: " + current_doc["article_text"] + " New: " + item_text)
                if current_doc['article_text'] == item_text:
                    print("Match")
                    # print(current_doc['article_text'] + item_text)
                    # print("Old: " + current_doc['article_text'] + " New: " + item_text)
                else:
                    print("Mismatch")
                    # print(current_doc['article_text'] + item_text)
                    # print("Skipping article as the text exists in last 10")
                # else:
                # print("Old: " + current_doc['article_text'] + " New: " + item_text)
                # print(str(is_new))

            # if is_new:
            # refresher_ref.add(result)
            # print("Adding document")

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

except Exception as e:
    # HANDLE ERRORS
    print(e)

print("Completed running.")
# quit driver at the end of function run
driver.quit()
```

Comment: `query` is a one-time iterable, consumed by the first `for doc in query`. Try `query = list(query)` before you start the outer loop so that you can repeatedly iterate over the contents.

Comment: @chepner you are right! That totally fixed it. I've tried to look up generator type on firebase docs but had no luck finding much about it. Feel free to submit it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`query` isn't a list, but some other iterable type that you can only consume once (similar to a `generator`). In order to use it multiple times in the outer loop, you'll need to create a list to hold the contents in memory. For example,

```
# query for last article
query = refresher_ref.order_by(u'article_timestamp', direction=firestore.Query.DESCENDING).limit(10).stream()

query = list(query)

for item in news_items:
    ...
```